# Impact of Decrease of dynamodb WCU

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement where I need to initialise my dynamodb table with large volumne of data. Say around 1M in 15 min so I ll have to provision WCU to 10k but after that my load is ~1k per second so I ll decrease WCU to 1k from 10k . Is there any performance drawback or issues in decreasing WCU.

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't. Once you've written all the heavy data to the DB just reduce the write capacity and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In general, assuming the write request doesn't exceed the write capacity units (i.e. as you have not mentioned the item size), there should not be any performance issue.

> If at any point you anticipate traffic growth that may exceed your
>   provisioned throughput, you can simply update your provisioned
>   throughput values via the AWS Management Console or Amazon DynamoDB
>   APIs. You can also reduce the provisioned throughput value for a table
>   as demand decreases. Amazon DynamoDB will remain available while
>   scaling it throughput level up or down.

**Consider this scenario:-**

Assume the item size is 1.5KB in size.

First, you would determine the number of write capacity units required per item, rounding up to the nearest whole number, as shown following:

1.5 KB / 1 KB = 1.5 --> 2

The result is two write capacity units per item. Now, you multiply this by the number of writes per second (i.e. 1K per second).

2 write capacity units per item × 1K writes per second = 2K write capacity units

In this scenario, the DynamoDB would throw **error code 400 on your extra requests**.

> If your application performs more reads/second or writes/second than
>   your table’s provisioned throughput capacity allows, requests above
>   your provisioned capacity will be throttled and you will receive 400
>   error codes. For instance, if you had asked for 1,000 write capacity
>   units and try to do 1,500 writes/second of 1 KB items, DynamoDB will
>   only allow 1,000 writes/second to go through and you will receive
>   error code 400 on your extra requests. You should use CloudWatch to
>   monitor your request rate to ensure that you always have enough
>   provisioned throughput to achieve the request rate that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a potential impact.

Once you write at high TPS, the more no. of partitions gets created which cannot be reduced later on.

If this number was higher than what is needed eventually for application to run well, this can cause problems.

Read more about DDB partitions for same.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html